# Infinitely many solutions for a first order Cauchy problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, cauchy-problem

Is this correct that the following Cauchy problem has infinitely many solutions?

> ‎\begin{cases}‎
> ‎xu_t+u_x=0 \\‎
> ‎u(x,0)=\cos x‎ 
> ‎\end{cases}‎

Using the method of characteristics it is obvious that it has a local solution around the curve $t=0$. But I am puzzled why it should have infinitely many solutions.

It seems that we can construct many solutions by Laplace transform method but I am not confident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the method of characteristics we obtain that $u$ is constant along the parametrised by $s$ curves:
$$
(t,x)=\left(\frac{s^2}{2}+c,s\right), 
$$
and $u$ is of the form $u=f(x^2-2t)$.

This means that the initial data cover only the region:
$$
\{(t,x): 0\le t\le x^2/2\}.
$$
In other words, the characteristics which start from the $x-$axis never arrive in the region. 
$$
\{(t,x): t> x^2/2\}.
$$ 
In particular, if
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\cos(x^{1/2}) & \text{if} & x\ge 0, \\
1+xg(x) & \text{if} & x< 0, 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $g$ is an arbitrary continuously differentiable function, then $u(t,x)=f(x^2-2t)$ satisfies the given initial value problem.

Comment: @ Yiorgos S. Smyrlis: thanks. I have a similar broblem which says If in the above cauchy problem we replace $\cos x$ by  $\sin x $. there is no solution. How to handle it?

Comment: @Finish Because, due to the fact that $u=f(x^2-2t)$, the solution satisfies $$ u(t,-x)=u(t,x), \text{for all}\,\, t,x\in\mathbb R.$$

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Out of curiosity, when using the method of characteristics, how do you know whether to parametrize as $(x(t),t)$ or $x(s),t(s)$? If you try the former on this you get $\frac{dt}{dt} = x$ and hence $t=tx+C$, which causes issues

Comment: @Hushus46 You always parametrise with respect to a new parameter, say $s$. Next, it might be possible to replace $s$ by one of the arguments. In this case, the $s$ CANNOT be replaced by $t$, but it can be replaced by $x$.